# zoom UIImageView image with drawing pixels also

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, drawing, zooming

I have UIImageView having image within it. Now i want to draw a line on Image, and when i zoom image the pixels of line should also be zoom according to image.

please give me suggestion guys.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw using a CAShapeLayer and put that onto the image, this is a vector using a UIBeizierPath hence it will re-scale accordingly when you zoom the image.